# Connecting a plugboard with the computer

Tags: raspberry-pi, hardware, gpio

I've got a plugboard which can be connected to a [Raspberry Pi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi) (via GPIO).

Now I would like to connect it with my laptop which haven't any GPIO port or something like that. So is it possible to connect it by USB or does it make no sense?

(I've searched for this, but I got only questions about 'software'.)

I would be glad to get an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick [google search for `USB GPIO`](https://www.google.com/?#q=usb+GPIO) returned a number of results.

These should work in a very similar manner to the ones on your Raspberry Pi, albeit with markedly less community support.